# Distinctive number from hashmap

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I need to know How can i calculate  distinctive number of words in `HashMap`

I got tweets and stored it into array of string like that

```
String [] words = {i, to , go , eat,know , i ,let , let , figure , eat};
HashMap <String,Integer> set=new HashMap();
for (String w:words)
{
  int freq=set.get(w);
  if (freq==null)
  {
     set.put(w1,1)
  }
else
     set.put(w1,freq+1) 
 }
```

let's suppose that `HashMap` now has all words that i need 
now how can i calculate total of number of  distinctive words ? 
that i can see that words that have value = 1 in hashmap right  ?

I tried to check

```
if (set.containsvalue(1))
int dist +=set.size();
```

but didn't work !

Comment: The map contains only one entry per distinct word.  You have not shown the code that added the words to the map, and that is where the problem is.  Also I don't understand at all what you intended with `if (set.containsvalue(1))`.

Comment: thanks for replying i edited the post , i mean for example if i have in hashmap i  3 ,  to 1,  figure  1 , know 2 , let   1 need to calculate total number of words that are distinctive  and as i got that hashmap conatains key and value key stand for word itself and value number of frequences right ?

Comment: Given this code, ALL the words in the map will have `1` as the value even if a given word appears multiple times.  When you add a word more than once you must increment the value... currently you are just replacing the existing entry with a new entry, still with the value `1`.

Comment: I edited the array . i 2 let 2 eat 2 but all the words 1 so I need ones only

Comment: I suggest you carefully read the Javadoc for `Map#put(key,value)`

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you well , can you please show more how can value will equal one even if  it appears multiple times ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    int dist = 0;
    for (int i : set.values())
        if (i == 1)
            ++dist;
```

Comment: thanks but i tried to write set.compute and didn't find it . i mean compute

Comment: Sorry. it is supported since Java 8.

Comment: no problem but what is the alternative ? i'm using java 6

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: thanks but i need to get total number of words that apprears only one time in this array , i guess your code get all words in the array rigth or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Before you put a word into set, you should check if the key exists or not. If the key exists, then you should increase the value.

Comment: Thanks but how can I do it? Is it like if (set.keys()==null) and do you mean key or value ?

Answer (score 0):

The following segment of your code is wrong:

```
  int freq=set.get(w);
  if (freq==null)
  {
     set.put(w1,1)
  }
```

**freq** is declared to be an **int** to which **null** check cannot be applied. **null** checks are applicable to references.

Also, I think there is a typo that you are between **w** and **w1**

The correct code is:

```
String [] words = {i, to , go , eat,know , i ,let , let , figure , eat};
Map <String,Integer> set=new HashMap();
for (String w:words)
{
  if (set.get(w)==null)
  {
     set.put(w,1)
  }
else
     set.put(w,set.get(w)+1) 
 }
```

Now if you iterate over the map to check the keys for which the value is **1**, you will have your distinct words.

Comment: thanks but my question is how can i get the items that have value 1 mean are distinctive

Answer (score 0):

You have just to iterate through all the map and get the keys with `freq == 1`

```
int unique = 0;
for(String word : set.keySet()) {
    int freq = set.get(word);
    if(freq == 1) {
        unique++;
    }
}
System.out.println(unique);
```